# How to upload large files to Azure blob storage in background and responding 202 accepted right away?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, task, .net-6.0

I have a file upload webapi endpoint where it accept `IFormFile` . I want to upload large files that are any where 100Mbs to GBs to Azure blob storage. I want upload the file in background and return 202 accepted as soon as I see the length of the file is greater than some threshold.

I have the following controller and injected service code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFilesAsync(IFormFile uploadedFile, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // some other code . . . . 

        if (uploadedFile.Length > _appConfig.Value.Threshold)
             result = await _fileService.UploadFileAsync(uploadedFile, fileDataType, cancellationToken);
             
        //map result and more code . . .
        return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetFileAsync), new { fileId = result.FileId }, mappedDto);

    }
    
    public async Task<FileUploadResult> UploadFileAsync(IFormFile uploadedFile,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var fileUploadResult = new fileUploadResult( . . .)
    
        _ = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var processResult = await _blobStorage.SaveFileAsync(uploadedFile,cancellationToken);

            // upload is completed, update FileEntity status
            var processStatus = processResult.HasError ? ProcessStatus.Failed : ProcessStatus.Succeeded;
            await _fileRepository.UpdateFileEntityAsync(blobFileInfo, processStatus, cancellationToken);
        }, cancellationToken);

        return fileUploadResult ;
    }
```

I have tried `Task.Run` but I still notice that the api still hangs when uploading using postman and I also learned that `Task.Run` is not recommended. What can I use in .net6 to trigger upload process in background and respond with 202Accepted ?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `background service`, `Coravel queueing services` and `signalr` to implement it.

1. Create a jobId in upload method, add pass it to background job method.

   ```
   var processResult = await _blobStorage.SaveFileAsync(uploadedFile,cancellationToken);
   // check the upload result

    // sample code, not test
    public Dictionary jobDic = new Dictionary<string_jobid, string_status>();

    private async Task PerformBackgroundJob(string jobId)
    {
        while(string_status=="uploading"){
            // TODO: report progress with SignalR
            await _hubContext.Clients.Group(jobId).SendAsync("progress", i);
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }

    }
   ```
2. When the file uploaded, then we can get upload success message, then we [can call frontend code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-7.0#what-is-signalr) or call [RedirectToAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

**Related Link:**

[1. Communicate the status of a background job with SignalR](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/communicate-status-background-job-signalr/)

[2. Repo](https://github.com/jerriepelser-blog/signalr-long-running/tree/master/LongRunningSignalr)

Comment: Thank you for your answer this looks interesting unfortunately I don't have flexibility to introduce  Coravel queueing services and signalr to the project :(